# How to increase thread timeout to allow long-running threads to complete without abend on websphere for z/os

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, mainframe

I have a JEE application deployed on WebSphere 7 on zos mainframe. One of the pages does a lot of processing with the database and the request may take up to 6 minutes to finish and respond. The problem I am facing is that the server detects that as a timeout (thread hang) and then goes on to abend the servant and restart the server. 
In my windows test enviroment, I get a thread hang message, but the application server continues working. The database connection works very well. So its not like it timeouts because of the database taking long time to respond.
I have tried playing with WebSphere variables to no success.
Has anyone faced a similar problem? Does anyone know how to resolve this issue.
Thanks a lot

EDIT: more info about the problem.
After the thread works for a couple of minutes I get the following message on the console

```
  Trace: 2013/12/16 14:56:57.849 01 t=8C6E88 c=UNK key=P8 (13007002)             
      ThreadId: 0000006d                                                           
      FunctionName: com.ibm.ws390.interrupt.InterruptibleThreadObject              
      SourceId: com.ibm.ws390.interrupt.InterruptibleThreadObject                  
      Category: INFO                                                               
      ExtendedMessage: BBOJ0113I: The Interruptible Thread Infrastructure is attempting to advance work running under request fffc77cb 
    Trace: 2013/12/16 14:56:57.850 01 t=8C6E88 c=UNK key=P8 (00000011)             
      Description: Log Java Message                                                
      Message: BBOJ0113I: The Interruptible Thread Infrastructure is attempting to advance work running under request fffc77cb 
    Trace: 2013/12/16 14:56:57.871 01 t=8C7AD0 c=UNK key=P8 (13007002)             
      ThreadId: 0000005a                                                           
       FunctionName: com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionEventListener                        
      SourceId: com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionEventListener                            
       Category: WARNING                                                            
       ExtendedMessage: BBOO0221W: J2CA0206W: A connection error occurred.  To help determine the problem, enable the Diagnose Connection Usage option on the Connection Factory or Data Source.                        
     Trace: 2013/12/16 14:56:57.872 01 t=8C7AD0 c=UNK key=P8 (00000011)             
       Description: Log Java Message                                                
       Message: BBOO0221W: J2CA0206W: A connection error occurred.  To help determine the problem, enable the Diagnose Connection Usage option on the Connection Factory or Data Source.                        
     ption on the Connection Factory or Data Source.                                
     Trace: 2013/12/16 14:56:57.873 01 t=8C7AD0 c=UNK key=P8 (13007002)             
       ThreadId: 0000005a                                                           
       FunctionName: com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionEventListener                        
       SourceId: com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionEventListener                            
       Category: AUDIT                                                              
       ExtendedMessage: BBOO0222I: J2CA0056I: The Connection Manager received a fatal connection error from the Resource Adapter for resource jdbc/mofaz19. The exception is: com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.un: A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream, or socket output stream.  Error location: Reply.fill().  Message: Socket closed ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001:java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
```

and after a couple of seconds the server abends and restarts. The last message as follows

```
Trace: 2013/12/16 11:48:49.543 01 t=8C9BF8 c=UNK key=P8 (13007002)              
  ThreadId: 00000363                                                            
  FunctionName: com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge                                  
  SourceId: com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge                                      
  Category: SEVERE                                                              
  ExtendedMessage: BBOJ0117I: JAVA THREAD STACK TRACEBACK FOR THREAD WebSphere:ORB.thread.pool t=008c4950:
  Thread Hang Recovery--thread could not be encouraged to complete 
  Traceback for thread WebSphere:ORB.thread.pool t=008c4950:                   
  java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)                        
  java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)                  
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.b(ab.java:195)                                         
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.c(ab.java:243)                                         
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.c(ab.java:354)                                         
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.v(ab.java:1139)                                        
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.c(bb.java:167)                                         
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.r.c(r.java:42)                                            
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.Cb(b.java:2514)                                         
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.jb.s(jb.java:1136)                                         
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.jb.q(jb.java:1097)                                         
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.q(b.java:4726)                                          
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.jb.p(jb.java:1072)                                         
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.jb.rollback(jb.java:1060)                                  
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.we.rollback(we.java:176)                                   
  com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.rollback(WSJdbcConnection.java:331              
  .........................
  .........................
  myCompany.MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:59)        
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)                 
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)                 
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1583)
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:870)
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:91)
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:863)    
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:182)  
  com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
  com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
  com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
  com.ibm.ws390.channel.xmem.XMemConnLink.ready(XMemConnLink.java:844)         
  com.ibm.ws390.channel.xmem.XMemInboundChannel.handleRequest(XMemInboundChannel.java:340)
  com.ibm.ws390.xmem.XMemSRBridgeImpl.httpinvoke(XMemSRBridgeImpl.java:104)    
  com.ibm.ws390.xmem.XMemSRCppUtilities.httpinvoke(XMemSRCppUtilities.java:74) 
  com.ibm.ws390.orb.ServerRegionBridge.httpinvoke(ServerRegionBridge.java:215) 
  com.ibm.ws390.orb.ORBEJSBridge.httpinvoke(ORBEJSBridge.java:281)             
  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)                 
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:101)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)                             
  com.ibm.ws390.orb.parameters.HTTPInvoke.HTTPInvokeParmSetter(HTTPInvoke.java:101)
  com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.nativeRunApplicationThread(Native Method)     
  com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.runApplicationThread(CommonBridge.java:463)   
  com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$ZOSWorker.run(ThreadPool.java:1750)
```

Comment: What have you done to tune your database processing?

Comment: thanks, I did all that could be done. The data is large enough to take the 6 minutes processing time. What I'd like to know is how to allow the thread to run to its end (max 8 minutes) without the abend occuring.

Comment: I'd like to add that the thread does many database calls, fetching some data processing it then updating the database. So it's not a database timeout waiting for a query response

Comment: Are you doing everything in a Web Container thread? (Blocking the browser while it's running). Or are you doing it asynchronously with an MDB or EJB or WorkManager?

Comment: I am doing it on a webcontainer. A servlet is the one running the code. And it blocks the browser.

Answer (score 1):

There are different timeout settings - on database, on web session, on http server etc.

Here is one of timeout setting http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.tspm.doc_7.1%2Finstall%2Ftask%2FConfigureTransactionLifetimeTimeout.html 
but there are a lot of others.

The common suggestion is to design your application without waiting for sync response on http. You can  use
MDB, MQ, WorkManager, TaskScheduler, whatever you like. On front-end AJAX call.

Comment: I tried various timeout settings with the server. The application I am dealing with is a legacy jsp, servlet app. Modifying it for the time being would be very hard to do. All I want is to just be able to prevent it from abending the server by setting the appropriate variable in websphere which allows the thread to run for more time before it marks it as hung

Answer (score 1):

The ITI timeout occurs when a servant region doesn't respond to a control region in a fixed amount of time.  See this [blog post](http://wasdynacache.blogspot.com/2012/10/interruptible-thread-infrastructure.html) for more information and some settings that can be used to adjust.

Comment: I want to increase this "fixed amount of time". I want the control region to give more time to the servant region to finish its task. Do you know how?

Comment: Dispatch Timeout Improvements in WebSphere Application Server for z/OS Version 7

http://www-03.ibm.com/support/techdocs/atsmastr.nsf/c6192fb3a432612485256d970082de57/3c02b79e79ea32fd8625751a005d7f63/$FILE/WP101374%20-%20WebSphere%20zOS%20V7%20Dispatch%20Timeout%20Improvements.pdf